# Update edited ComboBox items in database instead of adding them

Tags: sql, vb.net, combobox, edit, items

I have a combobox named "Barcode", I fill it from database like this:

```
Sub fillIBarcode()
    Barcode.DataSource = Nothing
    Barcode.Items.Clear()
    Dim adp As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter("Select distinct Barcode from Items where  ItemCode=N'" & (ItemsDGV.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value) & "'", SQlconn)
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    adp.Fill(ds)
    Dim dt = ds.Tables(0)
    '=====================================================
    For I = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
        Barcode.Items.Add(dt.Rows(I).Item("Barcode"))
        Barcode.SelectedIndex = 0
    Next
End Sub
```

And it displays like that:

[image]

When the user edits and changes any numbers in the combobox and clicks the "Edit" button, how to submit this change and update the combobox items list immediately in the database?

I tried:

```
Private Sub Editbtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Editbtn.Click
Dim cmdd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand
        cmdd.Connection = SQlconn
        cmdd.CommandText = "delete from Items where ItemCode=N'" & (ItemCode.Text) & "'"
        cmdd.ExecuteNonQuery()

Dim sql = "select * From Items where ItemCode=N'" & (ItemCode.Text) & "'"
            Dim adp As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(sql, SQlconn)
            Dim ds As New DataSet
            adp.Fill(ds)
            Dim dt = ds.Tables(0)
            If dt.Rows.Count = 0 Then               
                For i = 0 To Barcode.Items.Count - 1
                    Dim dr = dt.NewRow
                    dr!ItemCode = ItemCode.Text
                    dr!Barcode = Barcode.Items(i).ToString
                    dt.Rows.Add(dr)
                Next
                Dim cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder(adp)
                adp.Update(dt)
            End If
End Sub
```

But it adds the new value, instead of updating the existing one.

I mean it added three barcodes, the original two, and the new edited one.

Answer (score -1):

use SQL UPDATE QUERY :

- you must conserve dt across form event to keep old value
- dt has same index as combobox

declare dt as global in front of form code

```
Dim dt as datatable
```

in Sub fillIBarcode() remove DIM

```
dt = ds.Tables(0)
```

and in event handler execute an UPDATE query with ref to combobox selectedIndex:

```
Private Sub Editbtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Editbtn.Click
    Dim cmdd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand
    cmdd.Connection = SQlconn
    cmdd.CommandText = "UPDATE Items SET ItemCode=N'" & (ItemCode.Text) & "' WHERE ItemCode = N'" & dt.rows(Barcode.SelectedIndex).Item("Barcode") & "'"
    cmdd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    'update dt
    dt.rows(Barcode.SelectedIndex).Item("Barcode") = ItemCode.Text      

End Sub
```